# How to generate combination of characters in a string at a particular position?

Tags: python, string, combinations, python-itertools

I have a string list :

`li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Using the following code in Python, I generated all the possible combination of characters for list `li` and got a result of 256 strings.

```
from itertools import product

li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for comb in product(li, repeat=4):
    print(''.join(comb))
```

Say for example, I know the character of the second and fourth position of the string in the list `li` which is 'b' and 'c'.
So the result will be a set of only 16 strings which is :

```
abac
abbc
abcc
abdc
bbac
bbbc
bbcc
bbdc
cbac
cbbc
cbcc
cbdc
dbac
dbbc
dbcc
dbdc
```

How to get this result? Is there a Pythonic way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Edit : My desired size of list `li` is a to z and the value for `repeat` is 13. When I tried the above code, compiler throwed memory error!

Comment: a list comprehension that includes a test for inclusion

Comment: Lol. But the good thing is, I know 6 characters of the 13. So it will be somewhere in millions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from itertools import product

li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
combs = [list(x) for x in product(li, repeat=4)]
selected_combs = [comb for comb in combs if (comb[1] == 'b' and comb[3] == 'c')]
print(["".join(comb) for comb in selected_combs])
# ['abac', 'abbc', 'abcc', 'abdc', 'bbac', 'bbbc', 'bbcc', 'bbdc', 'cbac', 'cbbc', 'cbcc', 'cbdc', 'dbac', 'dbbc', 'dbcc', 'dbdc']
```

To save memory in case you do not need all the combinations `combs`, you can simply do:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
selected_combs = [comb for comb in product(li, repeat=4) if (comb[1] == 'b' and comb[3] == 'c')]
print(["".join(comb) for comb in selected_combs])
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. But will my memory hold if repeat is 12 and ```li``` has from a to z?

Comment: @raghhav Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def permute(s):
  out = []
  if len(s) == 1:
    return s
  else:
    for i,let in enumerate(s):
      for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
        out += [let + perm]
  return out
  
per=permute(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(per)
```

Do you want this?

Comment: Where is the condition that some letters should be fixed? This doesn't answer the question at all...